# error trying to recreate php's dechex function in python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, hex

i have a php file that takes a simple 8 digit id and converts it to hex using

```
dechex(intval($id))
```

i am now trying todo the same thing in python i start by grabbing my list of ids from the web these are returned as strings such as

> 00274956 , 00002645, 00000217

i then convert them to intagers and hex them using

```
hex(int(item_id))
```

but i am getting the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'init'

here is the code the id comes direct from a http get request

```
FILE_NUMBER = int(ITEM_ID)
FILE_HEX = hex(FILE_NUMBER)
FILE_NEW = FILE_HEX + ".pdf"
```

Comment: It just seems that one of the strings you are getting is `'init'` and Python cannot convert it to an integer. You will get the exact same error just by running `int('init`)`.

Comment: @AlexK the thing is i have use print(type(item_id)) and it returns str

Comment: The string does not contain digits, it's just `'init'`. You can't convert that string into a numeric value with the `int()` function.

Comment: how can i go about hexing it then ? its simple enough with php supprised it so hard to do in python its the only thing holding my donwload tool up

Comment: What result were you expecting from converting this string? You need an integer, so how are you going to get an integer from `'init'`? You can add code to filter out invalid strings that cannot be converted (e.g., with `try: ... except ValueError: ...`).

Comment: @AlexK i am grabbing a web responce that is json full of strings i am decoding it as utfand reading the json into veriables i then need to convert said text veriable into an init in order to hex it and get the hex value but i cant do this because i get the error inthe post i have printed out the veriable before hexing and it comes back as a string

Comment: Include all relevant information about your problem, specifically a sample of the json you are working with and what steps you are trying to implement, in the post, not in the comments. You can [edit] the question. Your problem is not clear right now.